# Auth based file download from Webserver

Tags: security, https

I have want to design(program) a https authentication based system, In which a Laptop contact to a webserver via providing its MAC address and user Information(String) as a user's device credentials in the request. The Web Server reply back with some files if the user's device is Authenticated and matched with the Web-server's DB which contains MAC address and User Information, if not reply the error message.

```
1) No Browser client involved,
2) The MAC and user information need to safe and should not be leaked I am using HTTPS.
```

Comment: And your question?

Comment: how to achieve this?